# On solr how can i copy selected values only from multi valued field to another multi valued field?

Tags: solr

I have indexed solr one of the field is multivalued and it has different values in it and i want to copy selected values into new field.

> Field1 has value a , b, c and want to copy into Field2 but only value
>   a and c

The data is came from another instance of solr using dataimport processor="SolrEntityProcessor"

Am using solr 4.9

Comment: Can you use a RegexTransformer to replace values that you're not interested in with an empty string? Using `regex="^value$"` and `replaceWith=""`.

Answer (score 1):

[StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_3_1/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/UpdateRequestProcessorFactory.html) that enables the use of update processors implemented as scripts during update request.
When we are indexing we get multivalued **Field1** and then copy those values which we needed into another field **Field2**.
[Managed-Schema]

```
<field name="Field1" type="custom" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="Field2" type="custom" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Below is the sample **update-script.js**.

```
function processAdd(cmd) {
    doc = cmd.solrDoc;
    id = doc.getFieldValue("id");
    Field1 = doc.getFieldValues("Field1");
    logger.info("Size : "+Field1.size());
    for(i = 0; i < Field1.size();i++){
        if(Field1.get(i).equals("a") || Field1.get(i).equals("c")){
            doc.addField("Field2", Field1.get(i));
        }
    }
    logger.info("UpdateScript processed: "+id);

}
function processDelete(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processMergeIndexes(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processCommit(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processRollback(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function finish() {
  // no-op
}
```

Add the StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory processor to the updateRequestProcessorChain in solrconfig.xml.

```
<processor class="solr.StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory">
   <str name="script">update-script.js</str>
 </processor>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! this is exactly what i was looking for. And it works perfectly. Incase someone wants to use this , some minor correction  `<str name="script">updateProcessor.js</str>` should be `<str name="script">update-script.js</str>` in solrconfig.xml and also `logger.info("UpdateScript processed: "+id);` to `logger.info("update-script processed: "+id);` in the update-script.js

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean *I want*? Solr can't read your mind. So, do you want to skip a specific value, an item in specific position, any item that does not match particular rules?

In all of the cases, most likely, you will use the UpdateRequestProcessor, but which specific one depends on what your business rule actually means.