# How to reduce the length of a multivalued field in Solr

Tags: java, solr

We have a multivalued field in Solr that we want to reduce its length.
A sample result response is as follows:

```
 response": {
     "numFound": 1,
     "start": 0,
     "docs": [
       {
         "created_date": "2016-11-23T13:47:46.55Z",
         "solr_index_date": "2016-12-01T08:21:59.78Z",
         "modified_date": "2016-12-13T08:45:44.507Z",        
         "id": "FEAE38C2-ABFF-4F0C-8AFD-9B8F51036D8A",        
         "Field1": [
           "false",
           "true",
           "true",
           .....   <= 1200 items
         ]
       }
         ]   
     }
```

We have big data, a couple of TB and we are looking for an optimized way to alter all documents within Solr and to modify Field1 to contain only the first 100 items.

Can something like this be done without the need to write a script to manually fetch the document, make adjustments and push it back to solr? Has anyone had a similar experience? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have faced this problem. But we use Two collections to solve this problem. Use **SoleEntityProcessor** to move the document from one collection to another.

```
[SolrEntityProcessor]

<dataConfig>
  <document>
    <entity name="sep" processor="SolrEntityProcessor" url="http://localhost:8983/solr/db" query="*:*"/>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

While moving pass that document through **updateRequestProcessorChain** where we can write **StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory** to edit our documents or to truncate the multivalued field.
In StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory you can get the field and apply your operations and then reset that field.

```
[StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory]

function processAdd(cmd) {
    doc = cmd.solrDoc;
    multiDate = doc.getFieldValue("multiValueField");
    //Apply your operation to above field
    //doc.setField("multiValueField",value);

}
function processDelete(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processMergeIndexes(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processCommit(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function processRollback(cmd) {
  // no-op
}

function finish() {
  // no-op
}
```

For More information on StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory, you can refer to this question
[On solr how can i copy selected values only from multi valued field to another multi valued field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761435/on-solr-how-can-i-copy-selected-values-only-from-multi-valued-field-to-another-m/40762923#40762923)
in which they edit the multivalued field using the script.